# Is it possible to reconstruct a regression coefficient from a truncated regression output?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, variance, covariance, partial-correlation

I am trying to help a friend solve an exam question and I fear that I am missing the obvious solution.

**Problem:** Students are provided a regression output from R. Just a simple linear OLS estimation with 2 explanatory variables and a constant. The coefficient and the standard error of one explanatory variable are removed from that output beforehand. The students were then asked to calculate the coefficient and the standard error from the remaining data.

**Information at hand:**
All what R outputs when estimating a normal linear model like `summary(lm(y~x1+x2))`:

- Estimated Formula
- Quantiles of the residuals
- Coefficients $\beta_i$ and their associated standard errors $se_i$, $t$-values and $p$-values
- Estimated standard error of regression $\hat{\sigma}_i$
- The regression's degrees of freedom $df$
- R-squared + adjusted R-Squared $\mathrm{R}^2$
- F-Statistic $F$, its degrees of freedom and its p-value

For the explanatory variable at hand, we have the $t$-value and the $p$-value but not $\beta_i$ nor $se_i$. Everything else is fully available.

**My thoughts:**

My guess is, that this exam-question is ill-posed, as $\beta_i$ is defined as
$$\beta_i = \frac{cov(x_i, y)}{var(x_i)}$$
And the above information is insufficient to reconstruct either $cov(x_i, y)$ or $var(x_i)$ as $(X'X)^{-1}$ explicitly was not given, which would enable calculating $cov(x_i, y)$ via

$$t_i = \frac{\beta_i}{se_i}$$
where
$$sd_i = \sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2 (X'X)_{ii}^{-1}}$$
and
$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{\hat{e}'\hat{e}}{N-K}$$
such that we could derive $\sigma_i^2$ from the standard error.

Alternatively I thought it might be feasible to infer the partial explained sums of squares from the other coefficients to derive the sum of squares explained by the variable with the missing information … and then using the covariance decomposition backwards. But this would (a) only yield the partial $\mathrm{R}^2_i$ and (b) would require us to assume that $cov(x_i,x_j)$ are zero and that $(X'X)^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix.

This seems quite convoluted for an exam to an "Introduction to Econometrics" lecture for business students.

My guess is that either

- a) I am missing the obvious, or
- b) the question is ill-posed

due to $cov(x_i,y)$ and $var(x_i)$ not directly being derivable from any of the other elements.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Interesting question, so they basically omitted one row of the summary output and expect you to calculate it from the rest?

Comment: They omitted part of one row, that is the coefficient and its standard deviation. The t-value and the associated p-value are there. At least that's what the student I am trying to help told me and she's adamant she didn't miss anything. Answers from the chair employees who she contacted were like "yeah it's totally possible, you just need to try but we're not telling you" … which makes me suspect they know they botched it. From the lecture materials I was provided I have no idea what part of the lecture they'd be referring to, as there is no problem set with a similar question.